# sails.hooks.views.render local is undefined

Tags: javascript, sails.js

When using

```
    AppointmentService.getAppointmentObject(req.params.id)
        .then((response) => {
            sails.hooks.views.render('report', { appointment: response }, (err, html) => {
                if (err) return res.send(500, err);
                return res.send(200, html);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message));
```

My html renders, and **appointment** is undefined.

---

When using

```
    AppointmentService.getAppointmentObject(req.params.id)
        .then((appointment) => {
            res.view('report', {
                appointment,
            });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message));
```

My html renders, and everything **works as expected**.

---

I've read through the hooks [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/a0de6578ef97a9ad2994faa77892faa46f772b5d/lib/hooks/views/render.js), it should expose my options (thus my appointment) as locals.

I've tried the following too:

```
sails.hooks.views.render('report', appointment, function(err, html)) // passing my object in directly
sails.hooks.views.render('report', { appointment }, function(err, html)) // es6 shorthand property
```

The reason why I need the hook to work is because I need to access the HTML in order to save it to my S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `sails.hooks.http.app.render`  not `sails.hooks.views.render`.

```
AppointmentService.getAppointmentObject(req.params.id)
    .then((response) => {
        sails.hooks.http.app.render('report', { appointment: response }, (err, html) => {
            if (err) return res.send(500, err);
            return res.send(200, html);
        })
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this problem by using res.render instead of res.view, which gave me access to the html.

```
    AppointmentService.getAppointmentObject(req.params.id)
        .then((response) => {
            res.render('report', { appointment: response }, (err, html) => {
                // I can access the html here
                res.send(200, html);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message));
```